# How to extract content after particular word?

Tags: jquery

I have this sentence in a page.

> Please contact the system administrator. Message:_27265.
>   Task:U_AW_GEN_M

How to extract the content and store in a variable after Message: and Task:

The number `_27265` and `U_AW_GEN_M` keeps changing.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried]
(http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also 
help us answer your question better.

Comment: You could use a regular expression. You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Regex (regular expression) is indeed useful in this situation - a possible solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex replace callback like so:

```
var codes = [];
var message = $("#userMessage").html();//however you're fetching the message
message.replace(/(\w+:)(\w+)/g,function(a,b,c) {
    codes.push(c);
});
console.log(codes);//["_27265", "U_AW_GEN_M"]
```

This particular bit of code works with any sets of codes, i.e. if you added to the end of that sentence `Foo:bar`, the result above would be `["_27265", "U_AW_GEN_M", "bar"]`

If you don't want that, change the regex to: `/(Message|Task):(\w+)/g`

**Associative object**

```
var Codes = {};
var message = $("#userMessage").html();//however you're fetching the message
message.replace(/(\w+):(\w+)/g,function(a,b,c) {
    Codes[b]=c;
});
console.log(Codes);//{Message:"_27265",Task:"U_AW_GEN_M"}
```

You can then access the task code, for example, with `Codes.Task`

Comment: Hi! SmokeyPHP, Thanks for the reply, I have slightly modified your solution to suit us. Thanks again.

You can take a look at it here http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/uT2Ne/

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "Message:_27265. Task:U_AW_GEN_M";
var msg = a.split(":")[1].split(".")[0];
var task = a.split(":")[2];

console.log(msg+"---"+task);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "Message:_27265. Task:U_AW_GEN_";


var b = a.split(":");


console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks but the Message:_27265. Task:U_AW_GEN_ keeps changing..it is not fixed.

Comment: what do you mean it keeps changing? via ajax?

Comment: No, from the back end. Depending on what the user has done, he/she gets different Messages. eg, if he clicked on button A he gets "Message:_28272. Task:U_AW_GEN_" or if he clicked on Button B he gets "Message:_45623. Task:U_AW_GEN_S" Need to get the values after : in Message and Task

Comment: @19eggs: He is showing you how to do this with an example. If you ran the code and used your brain for a little bit you would quickly see how you can use this to solve your problem. By splitting your input by the proper characters you will get an array of the values you want.

Comment: @thanks casey..used my brain finally..;o))

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/uT2Ne/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `split()` method of javascript.  This can be done without using jQuery, but since you have tagged the question with jQuery, I have used it within my solution.

You did not specify where the text would be coming from.  So I assumed that it would be within a webpage body.  Of course you can change body to whatever the container is that holds the text.

```
var text = $("body").html().split('.');
var message = text[1].split(':')[1];
var task = text[2].split(':')[1];
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teuWY/1/

Edited code to reflect efficiencies of other solutions.